# Using hot water on shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, water

Is there any heter to use hot water on shabbos - for say washing dishes, or for bathing children (not addressing issues of drying hair etc)?
Does leaving a faucet of hot water running before shabbos help in any way? If, so, how?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 aspects involved:

1. **How to get hold of hot water** on Shabbat without desecrating the Shabbat. This is a technical question.

   - You could leave the tap on, assuming the water remains how for hours on end.
   - You could invest in a Shabbat-hot-water system whereby no cold water enters the system on Shabbat, for example.
2. **What can you do with hot water** on Shabbat?

   - You could use it to cook items that won't have a Bishul issue.
   - You could use it to wash dishes assuming you need them again on Shabbat and you don;t have a Bishul issue (like washing off fresh lettuce in boiling water, which may possibly cook it.)
   - You could use it to wash, but only less than half your body, as documented in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch at 86:1 [סימן פו - דין רחיצה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0085_L2)

> אָסוּר לִרְחוֹץ כָּל גּוּפוֹ אוֹ אֲפִלּוּ רֹב גּוּפוֹ בְּמַיִם חַמִּים, אֲפִלּוּ הוּחֲמוּ בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת. וַאֲפִלּוּ לִרְחוֹץ שֶׁלֹּא בְּפַעַם אַחַת, אֶלָּא אֵבֶר אֵבֶר, אָסוּר בְּרֹב גּוּפוֹ. וַאֲפִלּוּ לִכָּנֵס לַמֶּרְחָץ רַק לְהַזִּיעַ, גַּם כֵּן אָסוּר. אֲבָל מֻתָּר לִרְחוֹץ פָּנָיו יָדָיו וְרַגְלָיו בְּחַמִּין שֶׁהוּחֲמוּ בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת‏

Comment: So assuming one left a faucet open - one would not be able to adjust that faucet nor open any other faucet, is that correct? I’ve heard of people allowing water to trickle the whole Shabbat from an open faucet - what does this accomplish?

Comment: _So assuming one left a faucet open - one would not be able to adjust that faucet nor open any other faucet, is that correct?_ - Correct, if you have a standard "water heater" system.

Comment: Are there other options besides - standard? If so, what are they? Why do people let the water run then, is it a misconception?

Comment: _ I’ve heard of people allowing water to trickle the whole Shabbat from an open faucet - what does this accomplish?_ Never heard of this. Possibly they have a heating element that turns on when the tap is turned on, so this prevents them from accidentally turning on the heating element? (Or the gas fire, as the case may be). But it doesn't solve that more cold water enters the system should they open the hot tap. Not a clue.

Comment: _Are there other options besides - standard?_ Yes - in Israel you can get systems that don't allow new water to enter the system on Shabbat. That and a Rabbi (as I probably don't recall all the details) will allow one to open the hot tap on Shabbat.

Comment: Any options for those living out of Israel that you’re aware of?

Comment: 'You could leave the tap on, assuming the water remains how for hours on end.' source?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Is it permissible to use the hot springs at Chamat Gader on Shabbat? Water is running. It enters the caldera cold and exits into the pool hot. Isn't this a discussion in Shas? What are the relevant issues?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between washing and immersing as discussed here: http://din.org.il/2013/02/08/טבילה-במים-חמים-בשבת/

Comment: And to expand the idea even further...   http://www.chabad.org.il/Questions/Item.asp?ArticleID=596&CategoryID=68

Comment: @YaacovDeane - how do you want to use the Chamat Gader waters? Drink? Wash? See the difference in my answer.

Comment: As I remember the discussion, they are curative waters. That was the basis of the discussion in their particular case. Similarly, looking at the discussion on the Chabad link indicates in connection with a warm mikvah that immersion for any mitzvah makes it permissible in general. The concern is aimed primarily in regard to the water being warmed in a permitted fashion.

Comment: @DannySchoemann You could check Shemirat Shabbat K'Hilchoso to see about bathing a small child/baby. Something like cradle cap might be curative and permitted too.

Comment: @user6591 I believe what he means is, if one leaves a tap open on a steady flow from before Shabbat, one can (if done in the right fashion) wash a dish as you are not doing any action, the water is flowing on its own...You would not be able to adjust the flow etc..

Comment: @Draizy I understood what he said. I asked for a source. This is not analogous to leaving a hose flowing water from before shabbos. Here one will be benefiting from water heated on shabbos, albeit heated in a non-assur fashion.

Comment: @user6591 What should the issue be if it was heated in a non assur fashion? How is it different than the garden hose?

Comment: @Draizy Water heated on shabbos even bihetter has special gizeiros at least.

Comment: @user6591 like what? Source?